# How to run PHP project with Apache from home folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, permissions

Old codeignitor project just won't run due to apache problem. Tried all the solutions found in other posts and other fora, but luck so far. It's a simple problem and I think it has something to do with permissions. Yet the permission settings seem to be fine.

Firstly, the problem. This is what I see in the browser

[image: this is what I see in the browser]

This is what I see in the apache logs:

> [Sat May 11 10:55:43.026415 2019] [core:crit] [pid 10672] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:38216] AH00529: /home/user_name/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/user_name/' is executable 127.0.0.1 - -
>
> [11/May/2019:10:55:43 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
>
> [Sat May 11 10:55:43.314120 2019] [core:crit] [pid 10672] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:38216] AH00529: /home/user_name/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/user_name/' is executable, referer: http://my_php_site.local/ 127.0.0.1 - -
>
> [11/May/2019:10:55:43 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 585 "http://my_php_site.local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"

Note that apache is trying to execute a .htaccess file in **/home/user_name/.htaccess**

I do have a **.htaccess** file in the project folder, and think that's the Apache should look for.

Secondly, my environment. Just in case I miss something I will give here my whole configuration.

The project is located somewhere in my **/home/user_name/** folder, and not in **/var/www/**.

File permissions for .htaccess:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user_name www-data .htaccess
```

Project folder permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 user_name www-data my_php_site
```

Since the project is in the home folder I have a rule in my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       my_php_site.local
```

The apache config for my site:

```
<Directory /home/user_name/code/projects/my_php_site>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my_php_site.local
        ServerAlias my_php_site.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/user_name/code/projects/my_php_site

        ErrorLog /home/user_name/code/projects/my_php_site/logs/apache2-error.log
        CustomLog /home/user_name/code/projects/my_php_site/logs/apache2-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, the .htaccess file itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Apache — with user group www_data — must be able to traverse the home folder. This means it needs octal value `5`, symbolic r-x.

```
chmod 750 /home/user_name
```

One Stack Overflow post mentions permissions for the project folder, but not for the home folder itself: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325498/apache-cant-access-folders-in-my-home-directory

**Following steps can also be necessary, depending on versions and system**:

Allow Apache to execute files in the home folder

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf`
Comment this part (put # at the start of each line):

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Add this:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```